# AttributeError when using googletrans module

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror, google-translate

I am writing code to make a ***translator using GUI***. My program runs but when I try to translate text it throws the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

##### My code

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
from googletrans import Translator,LANGUAGES

def change(text="type",src="English",dest="Hindi"):
    text1=text
    src1=src
    dest1=dest
    trans = Translator()
    trans1 = trans.translate(text,src=src1,dest=dest1)
    return trans1.text

def data():
    s =comb_sor.get()
    d =comb_dest.get()
    msg = Sor_txt.get(1.0,END)
    textget = change(text=msg,src=s,dest=d)
    dest_txt.delete(1.0,END)
    dest_txt.insert(END,textget)


root = Tk()
root.title("Translater")
root.geometry("500x800")
root.config(bg="#FFE1F3")

lab_txt=Label(root,text="Translator", font=("Time New Roman",40,"bold"),fg="#478C5C")
lab_txt.place(x=100,y=40,height=50,width=300)

frame=Frame(root).pack(side=BOTTOM)

lab_txt=Label(root,text="Source Text", font=("Time New Roman",20,"bold"),fg="#FFFF8A",bg="#FDA172")
lab_txt.place(x=100,y=100,height=20,width=300)


Sor_txt =Text(frame,font=("Time New Roman",20,"bold"),wrap=WORD)
Sor_txt.place(x=10,y=130,height=150,width=480)

list_text = list(LANGUAGES.values())
comb_sor = ttk.Combobox(frame,value=list_text)
comb_sor.place(x=10,y=300,height=20,width=100)
comb_sor.set("English")

button_change = Button(frame,text="Translate",relief=RAISED,command=data)
button_change.place(x=120,y=300,height=40,width=100)

comb_dest = ttk.Combobox(frame,value=list_text)
comb_dest.place(x=230,y=300,height=20,width=100)
comb_dest.set("English")

lab_txt=Label(root,text="Dest Text", font=("Time New Roman",20,"bold"),fg="#2E2EFF")
lab_txt.place(x=100,y=360,height=50,width=300)

dest_txt=Text(frame,font=("Time New Roman",20,"bold"),wrap=WORD)
dest_txt.place(x=10,y=400,height=150,width=480)

root.mainloop()
```

##### The error and stack trace

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\praful pawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\praful pawar\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9920\1422625581.py", line 19, in data
    textget = change(text=msg,src=s,dest=d)
  File "C:\Users\praful pawar\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9920\1422625581.py", line 10, in change
    trans1 = trans.translate(text,src=src1,dest=dest1)
  File "C:\Users\praful pawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\praful pawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
  File "C:\Users\praful pawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\praful pawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

##### What it looks like

This image shows that my application is running but something is wrong:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This library's own documentation says (bold added by me):

> I eventually figure out a way to generate a ticket by reverse engineering on the obfuscated and minified code used by Google to generate such token, and implemented on the top of Python. **However, this could be blocked at any time.**

It is designed to work around limitations that Google deliberately installed in Google Translate to make sure you use their official API (and presumably pay) to connect to their service programmatically.

I believe that what you are seeing today is that, as the author warned could happen at any time, it got blocked. The last release was two years ago, so Google has had plenty of time to patch the hole this library exploited.

##### PS: there's a ticket about this...

Well, I still think this library could get blocked at any time, but it turns out the library is still actively maintained, and they have a ticket open about this issue: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/354 I suggest you watch that ticket, maybe they will fix it.

I just tested the release candidate one reply mentions in the ticket, and it fixed the problem for me:

```
pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1
```

might make your code work.

Comment: You are correct - the usage examples on the pypi website for the googletrans module fail with the same error.