# I keep getting the error google_trans_new.google_trans_new.google_new_transError: 404 (Not Found) from TTS API. Probable cause: Unknown

Tags: python, google-translate

So this is it :

> google_trans_new.google_trans_new.google_new_transError: 404 (Not Found) from TTS API. Probable cause: Unknown

```py
from googletrans import Translator

translater = Translator()

out = translater.translate('guten Tag', dest='en')

print(out.text)
```

This is the code, it is supposed to print good day.  (Note: I run it in cmd.)

Comment: Your code currently works for me if I use version 4.0.0rc1. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73882068/3216427 It fails with a different error if I use version 3.0.0. What version are you using? (`pip list | grep googletrans` will tell you if you don't know.)

Comment: thank u it did work when i unistalled it then reinstalled that version much love

Comment: Glad to help. Happy translating!

Comment: In my case `pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1` didn't make any difference :(

Answer (score 4):

**Use `deep_translator`:**

I have not been successful using either `googletrans` nor `google_trans_new`. But the good news is `deep_translator` works seamlessly. You need to install it first:

`pip install -U deep-translator`

Then import it:

`from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator`

And use it as follows:

`GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en').translate("guten Tag")`

You should receive:

`Good day`